# itemize without environment

Tags: itemize, paragraphs

While formatting some text i was wondering if it is possible to achieve something similar to itemize outside of an environment.

```
-> this is an example of 
   how i imagine it to
   look like
```

as a result form typing

```
\one_item this is an example of how i imagine it to look like
```

Comment: the https://www.ctan.org/pkg/markdown package might help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following gives something like this:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\newcommand\tisitemA
  {%
    \tisitemCommon{2em}{\textbullet}%
  }
\newcommand\tisitemB
  {%
    \tisitemCommon{4em}{\textendash}%
  }
\newcommand\tisitemC
  {%
    \tisitemCommon{6em}{$*$}%
  }
\newcommand\tisitemD
  {%
    \tisitemCommon{8em}{$\cdot$}%
  }
\newcommand\tisitemCommon[2]
  {%
    \par
    \smallskip
    \parshape=1 #1 \dimexpr\linewidth-#1
    \noindent
    \llap{#2\hskip1em}%
  }

\usepackage{duckuments} %only for dummy text

\begin{document}
\blindduck
\tisitemA \blindduck
\tisitemB sublevel one
\tisitemC sublevel two
\tisitemD sublevel three

\blindduck
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: this works perfectly, thanks